# Rails 4.2.2 - How to implement annotator feature?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, annotations, tags

In rails 4.2.2, I am trying to implement annotations feature. I have referred this http://annotatorjs.org, but I am not getting like how to save annotations? Please suggest some more plugins(with full documentation) which will helps me to create this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Well, docs on the annotatorjs.org say that you need to implement a backend for [`store` plugin](http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/v1.2.x/plugins/store.html#store-plugin). There'a also [an implementation in Python](https://github.com/openannotation/annotator-store) that you can look at and a [working service](http://annotateit.org/) (it seems it uses that backend implementation).

I'd just go on the http://annotateit.org/, open the web developer console, made some saving and see what requests will be generated. After that you just need to replay it via Rails yourself.

Have a nice day!